# JavaScript If sentence ignored

Tags: javascript, if-statement

This should be fairly simple however it is starting to annoy me.

I have the following array:

```
var component_ids = [];
```

From my debugger i know that the array contains the following:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Now to make some page shifts i have created the following function:

```
    function next_page()
{
    $('#'+current_id).addClass('hidden');
    current_index++;
    current_id = component_ids[current_index]
    if(current_id != undefined && current_id != null)
    {
       $('#'+current_id).removeClass('hidden');
        if(current_id == component_ids[component_ids.length]) <-- This is the problem
        {
            $('#next').text('Færdig');
        }
    }
    if(current_index != 0)
    {
        $('#previous').removeClass('disabled');
    }
}
```

Now as pointed out in the code i want to check if it is the last page. which should be pretty simple however the if statement returns `false` or is being ignored for some reason.

If i debug it and check the result it does return true but is still being ignored.

Has anyone tried something similar?

Comment: Use `console.log()` to find out what the value of `current_id` is.

Comment: `component_ids[component_ids.length]` will be out of bounds - arrays are zero based so the largest it can be is the length minus 1

Comment: can you share a fiddle example

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As `array.length` returns the size of the array (which is 4 here), and array indices start from 0, the index of the last element is:

```
array.length-1
```

Try:

```
if(current_id == component_ids[component_ids.length-1]) <-- This is the problem
        {
            $('#next').text('Færdig');
        }
```

Comment: Your answer is most probably right, but could you provide a short explanation of the mistake in the questioner's code?

Comment: Thank you ... sad part is i knew that i was length - 1 but i am having a slow day :) but thank you for your help!